# Definition of direct sum of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, direct-sum

Let $\mathcal{H}=(\mathcal{H},(\cdot, \cdot)_{\mathcal{H}})$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{H}_1, \mathcal{H}_2 \subset \mathcal{H}$ subspaces. When I write $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_1\oplus\mathcal{H}_2$ this means that $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are closed subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$ such that

$(1)$ for every $z\in\mathcal{H}$ there exist $x\in\mathcal{H}_1$ and $y\in\mathcal{H}_2$ such that $z=x+y$.

$(2)$ The elements  $x\in\mathcal{H}_1$ and $y\in\mathcal{H}_2$ in $(1)$ are unique.

**Question.** The item $(2)$ is equivalent to saying that $(x,y)_{\mathcal{H}}=0$?

In the second answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164403/direct-sum-of-hilbert-space-subspaces-notation/164413#164413) it is said that $(x,y)_{\mathcal{H}}=0$ implies that $x$ an $y$ are uniquely determined. So, the converse holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse doesn't hold.

As an example, take $H = \Bbb R^2$ equipped with the Euclidean norm, i.e. $|(x, y)|^2 = x^2  + y^2$.

Take $H_1 = \Bbb R\cdot (1, 0)$ and $H_2 = \Bbb R\cdot (1, 1)$.

It is clear that they satisfy the conditions (1) and (2) in your question. These conditions in fact requires that $H = H_1 \oplus H_2$ just as vector spaces.

However this is not a direct sum of Hilbert spaces, as $v = (1, 0) \in H_1$ and $w = (1, 1)\in H_2$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: What is the definition of direct sum of Hilbert spaces? As in  the second answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164403/direct-sum-of-hilbert-space-subspaces-notation/164413#164413)?

Comment: It is given in the answer that you linked to. An equivalent definition would be: $H$ is a direct sum of $H_1$ and $H_2$ as vector spaces **and** $H_1$ is orthogonal to $H_2$.

Comment: Given two subspaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ finitely generated  using [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) can I always write $H_1 \perp H_2$?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is not quite relevant here, as it deals with basis elements.

Comment: Could you explain it better, please?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt works like this: if you have a Hilbert space $H$ and a finite set of linearly independent vectors in $H$, then Gram-Schmidt gives you a set of orthonormal vectors which generate the same subspace as the original vectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121208/discussion-between-guilherme-de-loreno-and-whatsup).